# java graph visualization w/ topological layout

Tags: java, jung, graph-visualization, jgraphx

Is there a graph visualization library which supports laying out the graph in a way such that
the X(or Y) coordinates of nodes are topologically sorted?
Alternatively, I could assign a number to every node, it could lay out the nodes in a way that their Y coordinates respect the ordering of the associated number.
Can [JGraph](http://www.jgraph.com/jgraph.html) or [Jung](http://jung.sourceforge.net/) do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JUNG does not provide such a layout but you can define your own layout algorithms.